# Connecting to a 3440x1440 monitor with a 2012 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, resolution, display

I bought a 34" monitor with a 3440x1440 resolution.

It works fine with my more recent Macbook Pro, but I was hoping to be able to also connect my 2012 MacBook Air and run it at a lower resolution. Afaik, the Air supports 2560x1440, so running at that with black bars, or full-screen at 2560x1080 would be ok. However, nothing happens when I plug in the Air via miniDP/DP or miniDP/HDMI cables.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, it'd be good to know what, if anything, you've already tried to get this to work? Also, what monitor are you trying to use?